# Key, Value in storageTrie

Tags: storage-trie

1. What are the keys and values of storageRoot? Values are probably whatever info the contract needs to store, right?
2. Is the storage tree of non-contract accounts empty, and thus the storageRoot, hash of the empty key, value pair? If not, what is stored there?

Thanks a lot for your time and efforts.